# WordPress Site Broken and it gives Headers Already sent error

Tags: images, themes, headers

My wordpress them is broken and Am getting the error below.

`PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/jcceastl/public_html/index.php:174) in /home/jcceastl/public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1430`

I've tried most troubleshooting steps but I have not been able to fix it.What could be the issue.

Comment: There's something wrong with your public_html/index.php file. The WordPress one is only 18 lines long, not 174, and does not echo out content itself. Have you deliberately changed that yourself? It should look [like this](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/6.2.2/index.php).

Comment: I haven't changed it. It came with the theme

Comment: No, the theme file would be in public_html/wp-content/themes/your-theme/index.php. That should be WordPress's index.php.

Comment: I suggest you take a backup of everything then go through the [Manual Update](https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/updating-wordpress/#manual-update) steps here, although it'd be safer to use the same version of WordPress as you currently have rather than the latest. Just the file replace steps - you can leave plugins etc. alone.

Comment: However it sounds like you might have unzipped your theme in the wrong place? How did you install it - manually? (That said, I'd be surprised if your theme's index.php was able to call through to wp_redirect, which is where that error is coming from, so there's something strange going on here.)

Comment: I installed it manually. The website had been functioning well for almost a year. Do I need to re-install the theme?

Answer (score 1):

> What could be the issue.

You unzipped the theme and put its files in the root WordPress folder, overwriting important files and breaking your site. **Doing this will always break your site.**

It only needs to happen once for it to break your site.

> The website had been functioning well for almost a year.

Irrelevant. It could have been running fine for 20 years before you unzipped into the root folder. The moment you overwrote WordPress files the site broke, it doesn't matter how long it worked beforehand. Overwriting WordPress files with theme files breaks things.

### How Do I Fix It?

You will need to remove the theme files that were incorrectly placed in the main WP folder `/home/jcceastl/public_html/` then restore the original WordPress files using a copy of WordPress downloaded from `wordpress.org`.

So:

1. Remove everything in the root folder except for `wp-config.php`, `wp-content` and `.htaccess`
2. Download WordPress from wordpress.org
3. Extract a fresh copy of WordPress into the root folder ( `/home/jcceastl/public_html/` )

This will allow you to use WordPress again.

**Alternatively if you made a backup beforehand, revert to that backup.**

### How To Update Themes Correctly

It should have been enough to upload a new copy of the theme via WP Admin. WordPress would see that it's a newer version of one you already have and update it for you.

To do it manually you replace the folder for that theme with the new version in `wp-content/themes`. Each theme is a subfolder containing the files for that specific theme.

Note that when you download a theme that theme/zip contains only the theme, it doesn't contain WordPress and doesn't go in the root folder.

Comment: Thanks Tom but it had been functioning well for about a year..Could it still be an issue with unzipping the theme?Plus am also getting a URL not found error when I try to access the /wp-admin files

Comment: did you unzip the theme into the root folder a year ago? What you're describing heavily implies you messed up installing/updating a theme by overwriting your entire WordPress install rather than just the specific folder. `wp-admin` giving a 404 also implies that you deleted everything beforehand, which suggests your `wp-content` folder is missing too. A theme folder/zip only contains a theme, it doesn't contain WordPress or any of the supporting files needed. It would be like installing a new kitchen by demolishing your entire house then building just the new kitchen and nothing else

Comment: and yes, if you unzipped your theme into the root folder where WordPress is located then that is a big problem, and is guaranteed to cause issues and break your site

Comment: I installed the theme  from wp-admin a year ago.I have not done any unzipping on the root folder ever since. I really need help on this one.

Comment: it doesn't matter that it worked for the last year, you only have to unzip into the root folder _once_ to cause this problem. My answer includes the steps you need to take to solve this, if you need additional help or a step is unclear please be specific about what it is that you need help with. Note that I can't fix this for you, and this is a question answer site rather than a help forum, so you need to ask specific questions that people can write a factual answer for that you can mark as the correct answer

Comment: I've made several edits to try and make the steps you need to take as clear as possible, if this does not answer your question please be specific. To be clear, how long the site worked before you unzipped the theme into the root folder doesn't matter and isn't useful for fixing the problem

Comment: I have followed the steps above i.e Remove everything in the root folder except for wp-config.php, wp-content and .htaccess,Download WordPress from wordpress.org
Extract a fresh copy of WordPress into the root folder ( /home/jcceastl/public_html/ ) but on opening the site am only getting a file not found error. Where could I have messed up

Comment: is the copy of WordPress in the root folder, or is it in a subfolder named `wordpress` or `latest`? If you're seeing a 404 then you haven't followed those steps accurately

Comment: it is in a sub-folder  named word-press

Comment: then that's why it 404's it's expecting `index.php` but you gave it `wordpress/index.php`

Comment: How do I resolve it

Comment: I  extracted wordpress files while in the root folder

Comment: I don't know how you extracted it or the tools you used, you need the contents of the `wordpress` folder to be one level up

Comment: I moved wordpress one level up and the website is still broken.Am still getting the error below from the console `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () wp-admin/admin-ajax.php:1`